# Yii: Disable direct access to Controller/Action, only valid if routed to

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I would like to disable direct access to a Controller/Action in the [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/), for example **login/get**, and only be accessible if routed to through [CUrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager).

In my configuration I am routing requests for **login** to **login/get** and **login/post** depending on the HTTP method:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'caseSensitive' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        // Rewrite GET requests of "login" to "login/get", and POST requests to "login/post".
        array('login/post', 'pattern' => 'login', 'caseSensitive' => false, 'verb' => 'POST'),
        array('login/get',  'pattern' => 'login', 'caseSensitive' => false, 'verb' => 'GET'),
    ),
),
```

Is there any configuration setting to disallow requests to **login/get** and **login/post**, or would the best way be to route those requests to somewhere such as **error/404**? For example:

```
array('error/404',  'pattern' => 'login/(get|post)(/.*)?')
```

Comment: Your solution with the 404 redirection seems like a good idea to me, what don't you like in this solution?

Comment: seems like it should be error 400 instead of 404

Comment: If this is the best method, then that is what I will use.
I just wanted to know if there was already functionality to do this that I wasn't unnecessarily repeating in a customer controller for errors. Thanks for clarifying that up for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your own solutions works just fine,
the UrlManager requests rules from top to bottom, so it will try the GET/POST first

so the full answer would be

```
'rules' => array(
    // Rewrite GET requests of "login" to "login/get", and POST requests to "login/post".
    array('login/post', 'pattern' => 'login', 'caseSensitive' => false, 'verb' => 'POST'),
    array('login/get',  'pattern' => 'login', 'caseSensitive' => false, 'verb' => 'GET'),
    'login/post'=>'error/404',
    'login/get'=>'error/404',
),
```

you can probably just use the rule you gave with regex

```
array('error/404',  'pattern' => 'login/(get|post)(/.*)?'
```